# mostrar valor en div con imagen cada 10 segundos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Quisiera lograr 2 cuestiones, la primera es que tengo una imagen dentro de un div, que simula una lucecita , la idea es que en funcion de la cantidad de registros de una tabla me muestre la imagen y por sobre ella el numero. Uso una funcion para traer el valor desde un php pero por alguna razón me borra la imagen y no me superpone el valor.

La segunda es que quisiera que la imagen , que es como un boton verde claro , titile o conmute con un color mas claro cuando el valor obtenido es superior a cero, que me conviene para esto ? Copio el codigo :

```js
    function actualizar(){
    $('#sensor').fadeOut("slow").load('prueba1.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }
    setInterval( "actualizar()", 10000 );
```

```css
  #sensor {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 29999;
  }

  #luxecita {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    z-index: 30000;
  }
```

```html
<div id="sensor"><img id="luxecita" style="width:65px; height:65px;" src="img/alerta_green.png"/></div>
```

Perdon por los errores , pero sigo aprendiendo.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo PHP.

Comment: prueba a cambiar setInterval( "actualizar()", 10000 ); por setInterval(actualizar, 10000 );

Answer (score 0):

básicamente, probando y releyendo, logré lo que necesitaba. Calculo se podrá hacer mas simple , pero cambié lo siguiente y ya puedo visualizar lo que necesitaba :

```css
  #contiene_sensor {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 10px;
    right: 320px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 29999;
  }

#sensor {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 80px;
    display: block;
    top: -82px;
    left: -2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 40px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", bold;
    color:white;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-shadow: -1px 4px 29px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    z-index: 30001;
}

  #luxecita {
    z-index: 30000;
  }
```

```html
<div id="contiene_sensor" class="animated flash" ><img id="luxecita" style="width:80px; height:80px;" src="img/alerta_green.png"/><span id="sensor"></span></div>
```

Gracias igual por las colaboraciones